# Unhandled exception in apparently trivial function call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I have a function that reads a text file and successfully returns a vector of the small number of lines in the file.  I passed this vector to a function to process the lines and it threw an error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00267EF9 in Bridge.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00A82000). occurred
```

So, as Ben Voigt pointed out, there was a stack overflow that probably had nothing to do with the function that apparently threw it i.e.

```
   int LinesToCards(std::vector<std::string>& lines) {
        int retval = -999;
        return retval;
    }
```

This was called from main which had a line needed by a 3rd party DLL

```
    int main()
        {
            std::string cards[MAXDEALS][DDS_HANDS][DDS_SUITS] ;
            int retval = -999;        
            retval = LinesToCards(lines);       
            return 0;
    }
```

The 
    #define DDS_HANDS 4
    #define DDS_SUITS 4
cannot be changed but the original working

```
#define MAXDEALS 999
```

now throws the exception.  If I reduce it to

```
#define MAXDEALS 890
```

the code runs again.  If I up that to

```
#define MAXDEALS 891
```

it crashes.  Is there some magic number between 16240 and 16256?

Comment: you caller isn't calling your skeleton function, is your caller function ReadFileStable by any chance? Infinite recursion would explain the stack overflow

Comment: Sorry, main calls both of them.  ReadFileStable just gets the input lines for processing by LinesToCards.

Comment: we can't tell you what the subtle problem with your program is if you don't show us the whole program

Comment: Absolutely true.  I have about 1300 lines of what was working, but monolithic and kludgy, C++ code which I'm refactoring and cleaning.  That drives several pieces of 3rd party C DLLs and lua scripts.  So it's all a bit fragile, and apparently straightforward changes seem to have consequences in unexpected places.  Once I get it sorted I'll try to summarise what the issues were.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of stack space.

The function where the failure happens is not the function that's to blame, and that's why it doesn't happen in your small test program.

One of the functions in the call path to the failing code was very greedy and didn't leave enough stack available for the functions it calls.

Look for both large objects on the stack and also too-deep recursion.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.  I'm refactoring stuff that was working fine, but which calls a very hungry 3rd party DLL and conceivably I've messed up some earlier call.

Comment: Somewhere else entirely I'm generating a file for processing by a different 3rd party program.  Nothing has changed in that code section and my generated file looks perfectly OK.  But, inexplicably, it now will only run with a blank header line and a blank trailer line.  Once I manually add those the stack overflow issue goes away!  Thanks for the help.